# Spring Boot Referential integrity constraint violation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, entity-relationship, hibernate-onetomany

At the beginning, I know there are lots of posts about this here on stackoverflow, I've tried every solution I found.

I'm creating a OneToMany relationship between my "ARTICLE" and "USER" tables - one USER to many ARTICLEs. The entities' codes are below (I'm also using Lombok, hence @Getter and @Setter annotations).

ARTICLE:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTICLE")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Article extends BaseEntity {

    private String title;
    private String name;
    private String iconName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
    private UserItem author;

    private Long editorId;

    @Lob
    private String article;

}
```

USER:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = { "username", "company" })
public class UserItem extends BaseEntity {

    private String username;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private String password;
    private String company;
    private String reasonsForAccess;
    private Integer failLogins = 0;

    private boolean enabled = true;
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean passwordNonExpired;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "USER_TO_ROLE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "ROLE_ID"))
    private Set<RoleItem> roles;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "USER_ANSWER",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ANSWER_ID") }
    )
    Set<QuestionAnswerItem> answers = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private Set<Article> articles;
}
```

My program initializes database by using data.sql file. I've put INSERT statements for the above tables in below fragment:

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ARTICLE(ID, VERSION, ARTICLE, AUTHOR_ID, ICON_NAME, NAME, TITLE, EDITOR_ID) VALUES
(4, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'book', 'Introduction to 1, Consumer Place', 'one', null),
(5, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'mail', 'Email Solution (Digital Marketing Center)', 'one', null),
(6, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'glob', 'Global Registration System (GRS)', 'one', null),
(7, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'ticket', 'Ticketing Tool to drive CRM work (Service Now)', 'one', null),
(8, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'pie-chart', '1.Consumer Place Reporting', 'one', null),
(9, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'sms', 'SMS Solution', 'one', null),
(10, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'list', 'Driving trial through Brand Propensity Model', 'one', null),
(11, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'line-chart', 'Data Integration Capabilities', 'one', null),
(12, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'application', 'What is DMP, CRM and DMP better together', 'one', null),
(13, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'bar-chart', 'Data Source performance Tracking', 'one', null),
(14, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'facebook', 'Facebook Leads Campaigns', 'one', null),
(15, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'cloud-glob', 'Learn more about Data Enrichments', 'one', null);

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.USER(ID, VERSION, CREDENTIALS_NON_EXPIRED, ACCOUNT_NON_EXPIRED, ACCOUNT_NON_LOCKED, COMPANY, ENABLED, FAIL_LOGINS, LAST_NAME, NAME, PASSWORD, PASSWORD_NON_EXPIRED, PHONE, REASONS_FOR_ACCESS, USERNAME) VALUES
(1, 7, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 'lingaro', TRUE, 0, 'admin', 'admin', '$2a$11$TiefIbi6p15IAlGZsTIxquCNDrRCCjmzt9lTN0/D.toRFDVG3ECYO', TRUE, NULL, 'good', 'admin@mail.com'),
(2, 0, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 'lingaro', TRUE, 0, 'user', 'user', '$2a$10$GS4IiuO9ygrHOr2e.lFx4euYACa6ZENz52KmGx8l.WCEqH03.HPsO', TRUE, NULL, 'good', 'user@mail.com'),
(33, 4, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 'lingaroaaaaaaaa', TRUE, 0, 'admin', 'admin', '$2a$10$AJMuV2lAeg1XQoPIYQklju9t6aWyVrPMreXVOCaRgJhoxsp831Yhe', TRUE, NULL, 'good good', 'admin1'),
(97, 0, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 'PG', TRUE, 0, 'hu_ta', 'hu_ta', '$2a$10$3opTpBQkdbvt8AA1aEOaM.YyCHh98ODxsPBlQ6IrX23o9HxUDyALq', TRUE, NULL, 'Ping Federation', 'hu_ta'),
(161, 0, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 'PG', TRUE, 0, 'tatar.ht', 'tatar.ht', '$2a$10$iDfgmuKJI1YHRK4DKsm4mOZ/CdnE.5GoWYijEzdsdU/SnulJCHRYS', TRUE, NULL, 'Ping Federation', 'tatar.ht');
```

After starting tests, I've got exception "Failed to load ApplicationContext", which is thrown because of "Referential integrity constraint violation". I've pasted only a fragment of the stacktrace because it's almost everything the same, just different INSERTs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)

...

Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKGWRTDBQVT9UCNTP82ND3YIUEC: PUBLIC.ARTICLE FOREIGN KEY(AUTHOR_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.USER(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ARTICLE(ID, VERSION, ARTICLE, AUTHOR_ID, ICON_NAME, NAME, TITLE, EDITOR_ID) VALUES (4, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'book', 'Introduction to 1, Consumer Place', 'one', null), (5, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'mail', 'Email Solution (Digital Marketing Center)', 'one', null), (6, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'glob', 'Global Registration System (GRS)', 'one', null), (7, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'ticket', 'Ticketing Tool to drive CRM work (Service Now)', 'one', null), (8, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'pie-chart', '1.Consumer Place Reporting', 'one', null), (9, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'sms', 'SMS Solution', 'one', null), (10, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'list', 'Driving trial through Brand Propensity Model', 'one', null), (11, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'line-chart', 'Data Integration Capabilities', 'one', null), (12, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'application', 'What is DMP, CRM and DMP better together', 'one', null), (13, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'bar-chart', 'Data Source performance Tracking', 'one', null), (14, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'facebook', 'Facebook Leads Campaigns', 'one', null), (15, 0, 'clobclobyolo', 1, 'cloud-glob', 'Learn more about Data Enrichments', 'one', null) [23506-197]
```

What can be wrong with this code? I've spent about 5 hours so far and I'm giving up, rewrote the relation thousand times with every possible solution I've found over the internet.

If it's relevant, you can spot the `Long editorId` - it's because I'm rewriting the code to include object with mapping instead of Long fields.

EDIT: I'm not the original author of the app so I didn't know about another .sql file until now - this one creates the above tables, maybe answer is here. I'm not sure though, because e.g. in ARTICLE table there is now "EDITOR_ID" column, I think the whole file could be deleted. As far as I know Hibernate creates the DB on the run by itself and it was working before I changed `Long authorId` to `UserItem author`.

```
CREATE TABLE ARTICLE(
    ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ARTICLE CLOB NOT NULL,
    AUTHOR_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ICON_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    TITLE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    EDITOR_ID BIGINT
);

CREATE TABLE USER(
    ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CREDENTIALS_NON_EXPIRED BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    ACCOUNT_NON_EXPIRED BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    ACCOUNT_NON_LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    COMPANY VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ENABLED BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    FAIL_LOGINS INTEGER NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD_NON_EXPIRED BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PHONE VARCHAR(255),
    REASONS_FOR_ACCESS VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    USERNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Also, the database I'm using is H2 if it makes any difference.

Comment: Have you tried first to insert data into PUBLIC.USER table and after that to PUBLIC.ARTICLE table?

Comment: didn't think about it, but when I do i get "infinite recursion"

Comment: Map your editorId with @ManyToOne